# Using Meteor authentication in configServer in call to createApolloServer

Tags: meteor, graphql, apollostack

I want to add a traditional rest endpoint to my Apollo server and I would like to reuse Meteors authentication system. However, `Meteor.user()` is not defined in this context. The endpoint will not look or ask for user credentials.

```
createApolloServer( ... , {
  configServer: (app) => {
    app.use('/myEndpoint', () => {
      /* I want to have a meteor userId here */
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Meteor, the best way to make a traditional REST endpoint is:

https://github.com/stubailo/meteor-rest/

```
simple:json-routes
```

and you can do authentication with

```
simple:rest-accounts-password
simple:authenticate-user-by-token
```

The best way to get Meteor user information in your resolvers is:

http://dev.apollodata.com/core/meteor.html